# How to use bitmap fonts with ILI9341 on the STM32f4

Tags: c, stm32, lcd, stm32cubeide

Can someone please point me to some info on using bitmap fonts to display on an LCD? I've written my own code to drive the ILI9341. I can send bitmap pictures to it and that works but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get fonts to work.

This is my function to send a pixel buffer to the display:

```
void lcd_pixel_write(uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t len){

    uint16_t *ptr;

    spi_disable();
    spi_16bit();
    spi_enable();

    cs_low();

    ptr = (uint16_t*)buffer;
    while(len){

        while(!(SPI1->SR & (1U<<1))){}
        SPI1->DR = *ptr;
        ++ptr;
        len -= 2;
    }

    spi_disable();
    cs_high();
    spi_8bit();
    spi_enable();
}
```

Comment: Do you _have_ a bitmap font that you'd like to use? That would be a start. It is (presumably) a large collection of small bitmap pictures, which you already know how to send to the display.

Comment: You might (or might not) find it easier to use something like [TouchGFX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/touchgfxdesigner.html), which can handle all of that for you. It needs some work to get it all set up, but then makes lots of things easier, like fonts.